# Instantiating at global level (C++)

Tags: c++, global-variables, instantiation

I get the following error with the code below.

```
expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token
```

--

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

class Foo {

};

std::map<std::string, Foo> map;
map["bar"] = Foo();

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your problem isn't "instantiating at global level", it's "trying to execute a statement at global level". You just can't do that, sorry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
map["bar"] = Foo(); // This line is a statement not a declaration.
                    // You have to put it in main, or any execution context
```

---

Untill C++0x becomes mainstream, I would suggest using `boost`. Filling the `map` becomes piece of cake. Here is an example:

```
std::map<std::string, Foo> mymap;
...
int main()
{
  insert(mymap)
   ("First",  Foo(...))
   ("Second", Foo(...))
   ("Third",  Foo(...));
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Short answer, as you've seen, is: you can't do that.

I think what you really want is this:

```
std::map<std::string, Foo> map;

int main()
{
    map["bar"] = Foo();
```

If you *really* need the initialization to execute before `main()` you will often see examples like this:

```
namespace {
   struct StaticInitHelper {
       StaticInitHelper() { map["bar"] = Foo(); }
   } _helper_obj;
}
```

However, now you have a new problem which is that there's no guarantee that `map` is created before `_helper_obj`.  One way around this is to combine them:

```
namespace {
   struct StaticInitHelper : public std::map<std::string, Foo> {
       StaticInitHelper() { (*this)["bar"] = Foo(); }
   } map;
}
```

Inheriting from STL container classes is generally not recommended, however.  Note that this example hides any other constructors and the STL base class does not have a virtual destructor.  This would be considered a "hack" by many, and should really be avoided.

Yet another alternative is to define the class with a `std::map`:

```
namespace {
   struct StaticInitHelper {
       StaticInitHelper() { map["bar"] = Foo(); }
       std::map<std::string, Foo> map;
   } map_holder;
}

map_holder.map.find(...
```

But of course this complicates any use of the map.

Update:

I forgot to mention another option, using [`boost::assign`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#map_list_of):

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

map<int,int> map = boost::assign::map_list_of(1,2)(2,3)(3,4)(4,5)(5,6);
```

I can't find information on whether that's safe on a static object, though.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you want is a static initializer.  I suggest you read [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.12).  Its illustrative of the use of static initializers and also of their primary pitfall, static initialization order.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I think I see why yours isn't a good answer. It doesn't address the question. Static initialization and the ordering dangers may be part of an answer to his question but you didn't include that.

Comment: There is no such thing as a static initializer in c++. Globals are initialized by there constructors. Also the linked article is terrible and full of really bad advice.

Comment: Well, far be it from me to contradict someone with such a high rating (and a grammatical error in *their* comment), but I call bullshit.  The C++ faqs is  a respected site which has spawned a respected book.  No, technically there isn't a 'static initializer' in C++ but there is a 'construct on first use' idiom which accomplishes the same thing, and if the OP is trying to initialize a global map with values, then this idiom is likely to be useful to him.